# How to call timer tick event of master page to content page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a timer in master page that checks if the user has a notification on a specific time. Every time the user opens different pages the codes in timer tick event in master page must be executed. I tried it but didn't work.

What must be the problem on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code would be a good start...

Comment: My codes was just placed on timer tick in master page,but it didn't work..for example if I place a code- if format(date.now,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")='2014-04-28 09:46'..this code didn't work event the timer meets the specific time when it must be executed